# Как получить значения Width и Height используя Auto

Tags: c#, wpf

Попытался найти похожее, не понял всё равно как.

Имею `tabControl` и в нем 5 `tabItem`, в каждом имеются разные `Canvas`. Чтобы не задавать при изменении окна размеры всех канвасов, использую везде `Margin`. Но, вначале при запуске приложения, в расчетах необходимы данные `Width` и `Height` разных `Canvas`. Можно через свойство `ActualHeight`, но это только если я заранее нажму на каждый `tabItem`. Можно ли как-нибудь программно получить их до отрисовки?

Comment: Пробовали вызвать `UpdateLayout` у каждого `TabItem`, а затем считать `ActualHeight`/`ActualWidth` у каждого `Canvas`?

Comment: @Raider Попробовал, в итоге всё равно показывается 0 везде.